# Using Variable in Excel Range

Tags: vba, excel, csv

Apologies in advance for the inarticulate nature of my question.  I am definitely a VBA amateur

I have a fairly long macro which essentially opens a csv, reformats some rows and saves as a csv.

The macro looks for a column headings like this:

```
ValArray(1) = .Match("CH4", RawWs.Range("a1:iv1"), 0)
```

Right now my company's staff are deleting the leading rows so that the header fields are in row 1.  Instead, I'd like to find where the header starts.  The header always starts with the word "ID" in column A.

So I tested this code to find the row where the header starts:

```
Sub findRowOne()
Dim SearchRange As Range
Dim FindRow As Range
Set SearchRange = Range("A1", Range("A65536").End(xlUp))
Set FindRow = SearchRange.Find("ID", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
MsgBox FindRow.Row
End Sub
```

I'm trying to take the number generated by this code and add it to the first line of code like this:

```
 ValArray(1) = .Match("CH4", RawWs.Range("a" & FindRow.Row & ":" & "iv" & FindRow.Row), 0)
```

It doesn't seem to work in the context of my larger code:

```
Sub gasExtraction()

Dim RawWbName As String
Dim RawWb As Workbook
Dim RawWs As Worksheet
Dim NewWb As Workbook
Dim NewWs As Worksheet
Dim ValArray(1 To 14) As Long
Dim Cel As Range
Dim r As Range
Dim DateTime As Date
Dim SearchRange As Range
Dim FindRow As Range
Dim firstRow As String




RawWbName = Application.GetOpenFilename("CSV Files (*.csv), *.csv")

Workbooks.Open RawWbName, local:=True
Set RawWb = ActiveWorkbook
Set RawWs = ActiveSheet
Set NewWb = Workbooks.Add
Set NewWs = ActiveSheet
Set SearchRange = Range("A1", Range("A65536").End(xlUp))
Set FindRow = SearchRange.Find("ID", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)

NewWs.Cells(1, 1) = RawWs.Cells(1, 1)


With Application.WorksheetFunction
    ValArray(1) = .Match("CH4", RawWs.Range("a" & FindRow.Row & ":" & "iv" & FindRow.Row), 0) 'change label
    ValArray(2) = .Match("CO2", RawWs.Range("a1:iv1"), 0) 'change label
    ValArray(3) = .Match("O2", RawWs.Range("a1:iv1"), 0) 'change label
    ValArray(4) = .Match("BALANCE", RawWs.Range("a1:iv1"), 0) 'change label
    ValArray(5) = .Match("CO", RawWs.Range("a1:iv1"), 0) 'change label
    ValArray(6) = .Match("INI-SP", RawWs.Range("a1:iv1"), 0) 'change label
    ValArray(7) = .Match("INI-DP", RawWs.Range("a1:iv1"), 0) 'change label
    ValArray(8) = .Match("INI-FLOW", RawWs.Range("a1:iv1"), 0) 'change label
    ValArray(9) = .Match("INI-POWER", RawWs.Range("a1:iv1"), 0) 'change label
    ValArray(10) = .Match("BARO", RawWs.Range("a1:iv1"), 0) 'change label
    ValArray(11) = .Match("ANSWER 1", RawWs.Range("a1:iv1"), 0) 'change label
    ValArray(12) = .Match("ANSWER 2", RawWs.Range("a1:iv1"), 0) 'change label
    ValArray(13) = .Match("INI-TEMP", RawWs.Range("a1:iv1"), 0) 'change label
    ValArray(14) = .Match("CHOSEN 1", RawWs.Range("a1:iv1"), 0) 'change label

End With

'do ID
RawWs.Range("a2:a65536").Copy
NewWs.Range("a2").Select
NewWs.Paste
Range("a1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "01 Asset ID"

'do DateTime
RawWs.Range("b2:b65536").Copy
NewWs.Range("b2").Select
NewWs.Paste
Columns("B:B").Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "dd-mm-yyyy h:mm"
Range("b1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "02 Date/Time"

'do Value1
RawWb.Activate
Range(RawWs.Cells(2, ValArray(1)), RawWs.Cells(65536, ValArray(1))).Select
Selection.Copy
NewWb.Activate
NewWs.Range("c2").Select
NewWs.Paste
Columns("C:C").Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "0.0"
Range("c1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "03 Methane"

'do Value2
Range(RawWs.Cells(2, ValArray(2)), RawWs.Cells(65536, ValArray(2))).Copy
NewWs.Range("d2").Select
NewWs.Paste
Columns("d:d").Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "0.0"
Range("d1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "04 Carbon Dioxide"

'do Value3
Range(RawWs.Cells(2, ValArray(3)), RawWs.Cells(65536, ValArray(3))).Copy
NewWs.Range("e2").Select
NewWs.Paste
Columns("e:e").Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "0.0"
Range("e1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "05 Oxygen"

'do Value4
Range(RawWs.Cells(2, ValArray(4)), RawWs.Cells(65536, ValArray(4))).Copy
NewWs.Range("f2").Select
NewWs.Paste
Set r = Intersect(NewWs.Range("f3:f65536"), NewWs.UsedRange)
If Not r Is Nothing Then
    For Each Cel In r.Cells
        If Cel < 0 Then
            Cel.Value = 0
        End If
    Next Cel
    End If
Columns("f:f").Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "0.0"
Range("f1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "06 Balance Gas"

'do Value5
Range(RawWs.Cells(2, ValArray(5)), RawWs.Cells(65536, ValArray(5))).Copy
NewWs.Range("g2").Select
NewWs.Paste
Range("g1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "07 Carbon Monoxide"

'do Value6
Range(RawWs.Cells(2, ValArray(6)), RawWs.Cells(65536, ValArray(6))).Copy
NewWs.Range("h2").Select
NewWs.Paste
Range("h1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "08 Pressure"

'do Value7
Range(RawWs.Cells(2, ValArray(7)), RawWs.Cells(65536, ValArray(7))).Copy
NewWs.Range("i2").Select
NewWs.Paste
Columns("i:i").Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "0.00"
Range("i1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "09 Diff Pressure"

'do Value8
Range(RawWs.Cells(2, ValArray(8)), RawWs.Cells(65536, ValArray(8))).Copy
NewWs.Range("j2").Select
NewWs.Paste
Columns("j:j").Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "0.0"
Range("j1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "10 Flow"

'do Value9
Range(RawWs.Cells(2, ValArray(9)), RawWs.Cells(65536, ValArray(9))).Copy
NewWs.Range("k2").Select
NewWs.Paste
Columns("k:k").Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "0.0"
Range("k1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "11 Energy"

'do Value10
Range(RawWs.Cells(2, ValArray(10)), RawWs.Cells(65536, ValArray(10))).Copy
NewWs.Range("l2").Select
NewWs.Paste
Range("l1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "12 Atmospheric Pressure"

'do Value11
Range(RawWs.Cells(2, ValArray(11)), RawWs.Cells(65536, ValArray(11))).Copy
NewWs.Range("m2").Select
NewWs.Paste
Range("m1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "13 Valve Arrive"

'do Value11
Range(RawWs.Cells(2, ValArray(12)), RawWs.Cells(65536, ValArray(12))).Copy
NewWs.Range("n2").Select
NewWs.Paste
Range("n1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "14 Valve Depart"

'do Value12
Range(RawWs.Cells(2, ValArray(13)), RawWs.Cells(65536, ValArray(13))).Copy
NewWs.Range("o2").Select
NewWs.Paste
Range("o1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "15 Temp"

'do Value13
Range(RawWs.Cells(2, ValArray(14)), RawWs.Cells(65536, ValArray(14))).Copy
NewWs.Range("p2").Select
NewWs.Paste
Range("p1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "16 Comment"

Rows("2:2").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp

NewWb.SaveAs Filename:=RawWb.Path & "\Land_Gas Extraction " & RawWb.Name, FileFormat:=xlCSV
' NewWb.Close


RawWb.Close
```

End Sub

Sorry, I think this explanation is a little scattered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it's not working is that `FindRow` is `Nothing`.

When the line

> ```
> Set FindRow = SearchRange.Find("ID", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
> ```
>
> runs, NewWb is still active so it returns `Nothing`

If your replace the first lines of your code with the following it should work:

```
RawWbName = Application.GetOpenFilename("CSV Files (*.csv), *.csv")

Workbooks.Open RawWbName, local:=True
Set RawWb = ActiveWorkbook
Set RawWs = ActiveSheet
Set NewWb = Workbooks.Add
Set NewWs = ActiveSheet
RawWb.Activate
With RawWb.Sheets(RawWs.Name)
    Set SearchRange = .Range("A1", Range("A65536").End(xlUp))
    Set FindRow = SearchRange.Find("ID", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
End With
NewWb.Sheets(NewWs.Name).Cells(1, 1) = RawWs.Cells(1, 1)
```

Comment: Should be `.Range("A1", .Range("A65536").End(xlUp))` Note the `.` in `.Range("A65536")`